# Was Titan II always unguarded?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* the Avengers attack Thanos in his garden on Titan II. Captain Marvel points out that the planet has no defences, no radar, no tracking systems, no armies and seems to be totally unguarded. When they find Thanos they discover that

> he has already destroyed the Infinity Stones

some two days previously.

Before this happened, was Titan II as vulnerable as it was when the Avengers turned up? The Avengers are only able to track Thanos due to

> the energy surge caused by destroying the Stones.

But, theoretically, if they'd found him before this then would the planet have been in the same state? In other words, did Thanos have all his minions and soldiers around him but just sent them away two days before the Avengers arrived? Was there defensive military hardware which was subsequently dismantled? Or was he on his own the whole time?

Comment: Does he even have an army left?  All of his main servants are dead.  Thor goes berserk and destroys all of the ships trying to flee the Battle of Wakanda (instead of being where he actually needs to be).  *"What did it cost?"  "Everything."*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### He was on his own the whole time.

**One** - Occam's Razor suggests that the simplest explanation is the correct one.  There were no signs of defenses or defenders, and had they been there in the past they'd have left some signs, so the simplest explanation is that they were never there.

**Two** - Thanos did not expect to need them.

> "With all six Stones, I could simply snap my fingers. They would all
>   cease to exist. I call that... mercy."
>
> "And then what?"
>
> "I finally rest. And watch the sun rise on a grateful universe....

Thanos does not expect strife.  He truly believes that the Universe will be grateful to him and that he can retire to a peaceful life.

**Three** - Thanos has hung up his armor.  Literally.

[image: Thanos Armor Scarecrow]

The fact that Thanos has hung his armor up to scare the crows away reflects how truly he believes he has retired to a peaceful life, and does not need his arms, his armor, or his army.

Comment: 2 seems to be key, his past self in Endgame even states something to that affect when deciding on the new snap plan.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'll try and pay attention during tomorrow's rewatch :) :) :)

Answer (score 3):

At the end of Infinity War, we see Thanos teleport onto that planet. He is not with his army.

He even takes off his armour.

In his mind, he had already decimated the only people who could've had the chance to go up against him.

Also, he had the full Infinity Gauntlet. So he didn't have much to be afraid of.

So, Yes, the planet would've been defenseless nonetheless.